# Converting String Builder to Strings Array in VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a RadComoboBox with check boxes and I want to loop through the check boxes with String Builder. After getting the values in that format: {1,2,3,4} I want to convert it to stringArray in that format (1,2,3,4)
Can anyone please show me how I can do this?

#### This is my code:

```
Dim sbPeopleTypes As New StringBuilder()
Dim colGroups As IList(Of RadComboBoxItem) = rcbFilterPersonType.CheckedItems
For Each item As RadComboBoxItem In colGroups
     sbPeopleTypes.Append(item.Value + ",")
Next
```

#### aspx code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" 
                    CheckBoxes="true" 
                    ID="rcbFilterPersonType" 
                    EmptyMessage="Select Person Type" Enabled="True">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the array by using the string's `Split` method, like this:

```
Dim myArray() As String = sbPeopleTypes.ToString.Split(","c)
```

However, unless you need to use the `StringBuilder`, for some other reason, it would be better to use a list, like this:

```
Dim peopleTypes As New List(Of String)()
For Each item As RadComboBoxItem In colGroups
     peopleTypes.Add(item.Value)
Next
```

Then, if you really need it as an array, you can convert it like this:

```
Dim myArray() As String = peopleTypes.ToArray()
```

Even if you did need it formatted as a comma delimited string, you could still build that from the list easily, without a `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
Dim csv As String = String.Join(",", peopleTypes)
```

Alternatively, since the `RadComboBox.CheckedItems` property is an `IList(Of RadComboBoxItem)`, you could use the `Select` LINQ extension method to get the values as a list or array without the `For` loop, like this:

```
Dim myArray() as String = rcbFilterPersonType.CheckedItems.Select(Function(x) x.Value).ToArray()
```

Comment: He also knows the length of the array, so he could just create an array `Dim arPeopleTypes(colGroups.Count-1) as String`, then do a for loop with a counter to set them.  Lists are great when used dynamically or where flexibility is needed (list, ienumerable, toarray, queryable, etc), but when counts are fixed, a straight-array approach also works.  However, performance on this scale would not be noticeable.

Comment: @ps2goat, excellent point.  That would be especially true if having the results as an array is really necessary.  If not, you could still get most of the performance benefits of an array by passing the size into the list's constructor so that it gets allocated initially and doesn't need to resize as items are added.